# C - opendir + fopen

Tags: c, file, fopen, opendir

I would like to know if it is possible to open a directory and then work with fopen to open a file from it. Like in the example:

I have a MAINDIR and inside of it I have file.txt so I would like to do the following:

```
void openFile(const char * filename)
{
    opendir(MAINDIR);
    fopen(filename, "r");
}

int main()
{
   openFile("file.txt");
   return 0;
}
```

I know i could do: **fopen("path/to/main/dir/filename.txt", "r")** but i want something more generic. Open a directory and then make every fopen work inside that directory

Thanks

Comment: `opendir` doesn't do that, try `chdir`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change your working directory using `chdir(const char *)` e.g:

```
chdir("/your/path/")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like messing around with `chdir`, you could just build the full path when you want to open the file:

```
void openFile(const char * filename)
{
    char fullpath[MAXPATHLEN];
    sprint( fullpath, "%s/%s", MAINDIR, filename );
    fopen( fullpath, "r" );
}
```

Although you probably want this to return something.

Answer (score 0):

`opendir` is for reading the content of a directory, that doesn't change the way relative paths are resolved. To change the starting point of relative paths you must use `chdir`:

```
chdir(MAINDIR);
...fopen(relative_path,...);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `opendir()` function does not do what you want.  Where available (which is not everywhere, as it is specified by POSIX, not C), it provides a means to read directory entries, but it does not affect filename resolution, which is always performed with respect to the current working directory, at least in implementations that provide `opendir()` in the first place.

On the other hand, POSIX environments provide `chdir()`, which *changes* the current working directory, and therefore the basis for resolving relative file names.  That could achieve what you ask.  Do note, however, that the working directory is a process-wide property.  It is usually a better idea to construct and use either absolute paths or paths relative to the working directory, and to leave the working directory as whatever it is at program startup.